# Excluding .cs but not .css

Tags: xslt, wix

I want to exclude .cs files using xslt and wrote this expression:

```
<xsl:key name="cs-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.cs')]"  use="@Id"/>
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('cs-search', @Id)]"/>
<xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('cs-search', @Id)]"/>
```

The problem is, it excludes .css files as well, but I want to exclude only .cs files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the last three characters to be `.cs` with e.g. `wix:Component[substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - 2) = '.cs']`

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach could be to cancat a character at the end of your string. But you need to be sure that this character will not be part of your string. Try:

```
wix:Component[contains(concat(wix:File/@Source, ,','), '.cs,')]
```